# cannot import csv, except from python install directory

Tags: python, csv, import

I cannot import csv. except from the Python install directory

I can import other modules, such as sys or math, from another directory. But I cannot import csv except from the directory that python is installed in. This is from the IDLE prompt.

```py
import sys
import math
import csv

contents = csv.reader(f)

# errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HBR\Desktop\python\betterway\csv.py", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader'
```

Answer (score 3):

your filename cannot be same with a module's name